# How to get the Time information of ECO events on Bloomberg when using tia package in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timezone, bloomberg

Assume I want to get the US Nonfarm Payrolls (BBG Ticker: NFP TCH Index) data for 2023 from Bloomberg using the tia package. I'm interested in fetching the Date of announcement, the time (in UK timezone) and the survey median value. This is how the last 3 rows looks on the ECO page (Note the 12:30 UK time in November is different to the usual 13:30 time of other months):

| Date | Time | Median |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/06 | 13:30 | XXX |
| 11/03 | 12:30 | YYY |
| 12/08 | 13:30 | ZZZ |

What I did so far is (using Python 2.7 version for compatibility with tia package):

```
import pandas as pd
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm

mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
ticker = "NFP TCH Index"
sid = mgr[ticker]

df = sid.get_historical(["BN_SURVEY_MEDIAN"], start="1/1/2023", end="12/31/2023", DT631="1")
```

Note: the override field DT631 set to 1 is used so that the dates are returned as the actual announcement dates, and not the end-of-month dates.

What my returned dataframe looks like is as follows:

| Date | Median |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-06 00:00:00 | XXX |
| 2023-11-03 00:00:00 | YYY |
| 2023-12-08 00:00:00 | ZZZ |

The dates match, the median values match, but the time returned shows as 00:00:00 for all entries, instead of 13:30 or 12:30.

Is there a way to modify my code to get the announcement time too (e.g. 13:30, 12:30 and 13:30 for the last 3 rows respectively)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `tia` so not posting an answer as such. Probably need a 2-stage query: the first as you have already used, then either (a) use the bulk data field `ECO_FUTURE_RELEASE_DATE_LIST`, parse that into separate date and time, then lookup into that array (`=BDS()` in Excel) or (b) for each survey date query `ECO_FUTURE_RELEASE_DATE` using the `START_DT` override (`=BDP()`) and parse that result for time. Of the two (a) is more efficient (as fewer Bloomberg calls), but depends on whether you can query bulk data in `tia`.